# Google Geocoding $.ajax()

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-maps-api-3

I'm having trouble getting the "error:" part of the ajax function to fire using the Google reverse Geocoding api.

http://codepen.io/mustachios/pen/sdwIG

Most zip codes will work, but if you put in a too long string ("12345678" for instance), the error alert doesn't fire, the console just says my result is undefined.

Should I just be checking for undefined inside the "success:" part of the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
success:function(result){

    //console.log(result);

    if(result.results[0]){
       var addresses = result.results[0].address_components;
    }
    else{
       alert('error');
    }
```

If the post code doesn't exist result.results[0].address_components is non-existant, it's result.results[0] that would be undefined. So after the user clicks 'Submit', check to see if result.results[0] exists via `if(result.results[0])` then assign `addresses` if it does, or `alert('error')` if it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

1. AFAIK in there is no `failure`-callback, it has to be `error`
2. the geocoder will always return a valid JSON and a HTTP-statuscode 200, even when there is no result. You must check the status-property of the response, it has to be `OK`  , otherwise there is no result.